# Multisite permalinks for subfolder wordpress installation

Tags: htaccess

I have WordPress installed in a subfolder of the main site: `http://www.example.com/blog/`

Now I need to add second blog on `http://www.example.com/blog/second/`

So 2 blogs should work on the following URLs:

1. `www.example.com/blog/`
2. `www.example.com/blog/second/`

I configures WordPress and almost everything works fine, but I have a little issue with the main blog (`www.example.com/blog/`), the post URLs look like **/blog/blog/hello-world/** rather than **/blog/hello-world/**.
Second blog URLs work properly.

I tried to change permalink structure in site settings to /%postname%/, and all URLs look good after that, but all they cause 404 error.

How can I get rid of double /blog mention in this case? Thanks in advance!

wp-config settings:

```
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.mysite.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/blog/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to setup categories and post in `/blog/` and `/blog/second/` and publish according. You can setup permissions based on category. The problem you have is that you've effectively setup another WordPress in /blog/ which would crash with your currently blog so you need to install it as `/x/` so that way you'd have `/x/blog/` if you want to use `/blog/second/` then your `define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/blog/');` needs to be `define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/blog/second/');`

Comment: Here's an example of 2 blogs with similar URL structure: http://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/finance/ , http://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/ - so it's possible to have it worked.

Comment: Yes, they will be using `define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/blog/second/');` also you could always just install WordPress into a directory rather than using multisite. Having a 2nd install has its own benefits.